# why the code inside EOF shows this error?

Tags: bash, shell

I have this script with all the functions and when the script is executed I need to create another script with EOF and open it through first script but when I create the file with eof and I try to write the code of the script it shows this error:

./skriptaTjeter.sh: line 6: [: : integer expression expected

./skriptaTjeter.sh: line 9: [: : integer expression expected

./skriptaTjeter.sh: line 13: [: : integer expression expected

numer pozitiv ju lutem

I just started with bash scripts and I don't understand what I did wrong

```
cat > skriptaTjeter.sh <<EOF
#! /bin/bash

clear
echo Shkruani te ardhurat
read vlera
if [ "$vlera" -lt 5000 ]
then
    echo nuk ka asnje takse
elif [ "$vlera" -ge 5000 ] && [ "$vlera" -le 30000 ]
then
    tatimi=$((vlera*10/100))
    echo shkalla tatimore eshte 10% : $tatimi
elif [ "$vlera" -gt 30000 ]
then
    tatimi=$((vlera*20/100))
    echo shkalla tatimore eshte 20% : $tatimi
else 
    echo numer pozitiv ju lutem
fi


EOF


./skriptaTjeter.sh
```

Comment: Why are you creating a separate file and then executing it instead of just executing in-place the code you're writing to that file?

Comment: it's an assignment from uni and that's the way they want it done,I completed with just one script but they said to use EOF

Answer (score 2):

`$vlera` is being expanded before `cat` runs, so your script has lines like

```
if [ "" -lt 5000 ]
```

You want to quote the delimiter so that no parameter expansion occurs in the here document:

```
cat > skriptaTjeter.sh <<'EOF'
...
EOF
```

Comment: Thank you very much I didn't realize that,now is fine

Comment: I need to navigate through first script and other script which I created with eof while executing,how can I do that?

Comment: I done it but everytime I change the terminal execution from script to script eof create a new script file